# Deobfuscate Sitecore.Kernell.dll

Tags: link-manager

If anyone has been able to deobfuscate Sitecore.Kernell.dll to debug an issue, can you kindly list the steps. I need to investigate a prod issue with LinkManager. On adding log lines upto the point where our code hands over to LinkManager.GetItemUrl, we can confirm that the options.Site, Context.Site, item.Path are all as expected. But, the return url from Sitecore is for some other random item. So I need to add log lines to the code in Sitecore.Kernell.dll to debug the issue.

Comment: It's a known bug. Linked you the reference. Also; Sitecore.Kernel is not obfuscated. Which you would have known if you gave it half a look.

Comment: Please don't close the question by linking possible answers without checking whether the answers marked did actually solve the issue. I was the one who raised the linked question and wouldn't have raised another one if the answers had resolved the issue.

Comment: @tiger here you go: https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Debugging-framework-internals-without-source-code

Comment: To fix the issue we ended up implementing a CustomUrlBuilder and patching it in place of Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel